# Ensemble learning with models of different quality. Develop a voting method that takes accuracy, F1, recall, calibration of each model into account

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, ensemble-learning

Lets assume I have 24 random forest models. Each of 24 random forest models produces a class prediction. I am currently using simple majority voting to select final prediction. Can someone please guide me in the direction of other options that I can use? Specifically , weighted or using another model on top of this?
I see that out of 24 random forests, some have quite bad recall and f1 scores, some are also really badly calibrated. Thus, I want to develop a voting method that takes this into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of options that would be straightforward for you to implement:

1. What you are doing is called *hard voting* i.e. each model votes on the class outcome. A likely better option is *soft voting*, in which each model's vote is weighted by its confidence. I've explained this in more detail here: [Hard voting, soft voting in ensemble based methods](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349540/hard-voting-soft-voting-in-ensemble-based-methods/349556#349556)
2. Another way to integrate the information in the separate models is [stacking](/questions/tagged/stacking). This involves training a different model on the predictions of the individual models in the ensemble.

In general, there's only a few strategies that are generally used to integrate different machine learning models, discussed well in this thread: [Bagging, boosting and stacking in machine learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18891/bagging-boosting-and-stacking-in-machine-learning)